# why my app script code makes copy of the spreadsheet to the root directory of google drive in addition to the specific directory?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i have a spreadsheet and i save this sheet to a particular folder with the code below. if a file with the same name exists in this folder, it deletes the old one and then adds the new one. it was working well. but a few weeks ago it has started also to make copy to the root directory of google drive. it makes two copies of the sheet. one is to the directory i give and the other one (which is not wanted)is to the root directory.

i have been looking and looking but can't see the reason. can anyone help me about what is wrong with my code?

```
function copyToFolder_trigger(){
  copyToFolder(folderID_ARSIV, sheet_Parklar);
}

function copyToFolder(folderid, spreadsheet){  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet);
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid); 
  var date = getDailyDate();  
  
  if(isinFolder(folderid, date)){
    var fileIterator = destFolder.getFilesByName(date);
    while(fileIterator.hasNext()){
      var file = fileIterator.next();
      destFolder.removeFile(file);
    }
  }
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(date, destFolder); 
  
}


function isinFolder(folderId, filename){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();  
  var res = false; 
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    
      if(file == filename){ 
        res = true;
        break;
      }
  }  
  return res;
}
```

[archive folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eagz.png)

[root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og6JA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I have no idea what's going on. But when I changed the line:

```
destFolder.removeFile(file);
```

to:

```
 file.setTrashed(true);
```

It started work well. For me. For now...